# HREF is getting applied to entire Line, instead of only the words

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline-visualforce

I am a novice Salesforce developer, and I am stuck with one issue.
I want to apply a Hyperlink to set of Words, but it is getting applied to the entire line.

The code is:

```
<div class="instance-section">
    <h1>History</h1>

    <apex:outputPanel>
        <a class="testClass" target="_top" href="{!$Site.Prefix}/home/home.jsp"> &lt;&lt; back to portal</a>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</div>
```

Here, the entire line of BACK TO PORTAL shows the hyperlink, i mean from the left of the screen to the right.

I want only the words to act as the link, which is the normal scenario.
I have tried putting SPAN, using OutputText, with no success.

Please help. Thanks.

[image: The entire line acting as a link.]

Comment: Could you post an image and give us the css?

Comment: @feddus Hi, I don't have the access to the CSS.

Comment: try to remove class="testClass" and see if something happens

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This could be the CSS style "testClass" specifying the width of the element.

Try it without the style applied to confirm that it is the result of the style.

```
<div class="instance-section">
    <h1>History</h1>

    <apex:outputPanel>
        <a target="_top" href="{!$Site.Prefix}/home/home.jsp"> &lt;&lt; back to portal</a>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</div>
```

Once confirmed, you can check the style and amend it appropriately

--- edit, since you can't amend the CSS

You can try either
a) leave the class in, and override the particular parts that you want to remove in the style tag

```
<a target="_top" class="testClass" style="width=...(or whatever)" href="{!$Site.Prefix}/home/home.jsp"> &lt;&lt; back to portal</a>
```

b) remove the class, and recreate the bits you want to keep in the style tag

```
<a target="_top" style="...the bits of style that are applicable..." href="{!$Site.Prefix}/home/home.jsp"> &lt;&lt; back to portal</a>
```

Comment: Can you share the CSS definition of "testClass"?

Comment: I dont have access to the CSS. Considering that there IS a width definition, can it be overriden ?

Comment: You can use something like FireBug extension in Firefox, or Web Developer in Chrome to see what style is being applied to the rendered page.

Comment: I have found that the 'testClass' is the culprit. After removing it, normal functionality is being restored. But I dont have the access to the CSS.

Comment: Is there a way to override the 'testClass'?

Comment: You should be able to use the inline style attribute of the <a> element. I've shown this in the answer now. This will generally override the CSS as long as the CSS doesn't specify !important

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my Vf page, the same code. Its appearing as given below. Please share your screenshot if it is not appearing like this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, I have added the snapshot as it appears on my screen in the question. I had made some text changes to make the readability easier.